# Validate a custom sort in a List of String

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to validate if a returned list is sorted, but by a predefined sorting algorithm. If the list is not sorted then I should sort it via that custom sort.

I already implemented the custom sorting function, however I want to validate if the retrieved list is sorted according to that custom sort.

This is the code for the custom sort:

```
public static void customSort(final String order, String[] array){
        String[] alphabets = {"!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", "/",
                "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "=",
                "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x",  "y", "z",
                "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
                "[", "]", "_"
        };
        String keyword = order;
        for(int g = 0; g < alphabets.length; g++){
            String one = alphabets[g];
            if(!keyword.contains(one)){
                keyword = keyword + one;
            }
        }

        final String finalKeyword = keyword;
        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                int pos1 = 0;
                int pos2 = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(o1.length(), o2.length()) && pos1 == pos2; i++) {
                    pos1 = finalKeyword.indexOf(o1.charAt(i));
                    pos2 = finalKeyword.indexOf(o2.charAt(i));
                }

                if (pos1 == pos2 && o1.length() != o2.length()) {
                    return o1.length() - o2.length();
                }

                return pos1  - pos2  ;
            }
        });



 public static void main(String args[]){
       final String order = "!@#$%^ ()*+,-/0123456789=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]_";
customSort(order,  arr);
    }
```

Comment: You wrote "List" and tagged this question with "arraylist", but where is that list? You only work with arrays.

Comment: the retrieved data is a list/arraylist

Comment: " If the list is not sorted then I should sort it via that custom sort."  This implies you trust the result of the custom sort - so just sort the "retrieved list" (you don't explain that very well but assume you got it from another source) - if you need to know if the "retrieved list" was not sorted according to the custom sort then simply compare the retrieved list to the sorted list.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I should've explained more the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing because you're saying that your method needs to validate if the input is in order but sort it if it isn't. Since this is effectively the same things as sorting it, that's what I'm implementing.

The solution that you provided does have some bugs. For instance, you're changing pos1 and pos2 in the for loop, but only checking those values once the for loop terminates.

In the solution I'm providing, I build a lookup map to find the order of a character, which is much more efficient then performing an indexOf on a string whenever a comparison has to be made. Additionally, every time we come across a character that is not in the input order or ALL_CHARS, we just add it to the map with the highest position (sorting it last).

```
public final static String ALL_CHARS = "!@#$%^&()*+,-/0123456789=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]_";

public static void customSort(String order, String[] array) {
    final Map<Character, Integer> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
    String temp = order + ALL_CHARS;
    int len = temp.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        orderMap.putIfAbsent(temp.charAt(i), orderMap.size());
    }

    Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int min = Math.min(o1.length(), o2.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
                Integer pos1 = orderMap.get(o1.charAt(i));
                if (pos1 == null) {
                    // character not found, add it to the "end" of our ordering map
                    pos1 = orderMap.size();
                    orderMap.put(o1.charAt(i), pos1);
                }
                Integer pos2 = orderMap.get(o2.charAt(i));
                if (pos2 == null) {
                    // character not found, add it to the "end" of our ordering map
                    pos2 = orderMap.size();
                    orderMap.put(o2.charAt(i), pos2);
                }
                if (pos1 != pos2)
                    // If their different, we now know the ordering
                    return pos1 - pos2;
            }
            // If the start with the same characters, the shortest string should be first
            return o1.length() - o2.length();
        }
    });
}

@Test
public void testCustomSort() {
    String[] test = new String[] { "cat", "cats" };
    customSort("cba", test);
    assertEquals("cat", test[0]);
    customSort("abc", test);
    assertEquals("cat", test[0]);

    test = new String[] { "cat", "dog" };
    customSort("abcd", test);
    assertEquals("cat", test[0]);
    customSort("dcba", test);
    assertEquals("dog", test[0]);

}
```